# How to create curves in React Native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a curved View's in React Native but it seems like this's impossible to achieve. I'm try to create the following [view with inset shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgwXp.png) and a custom bottom navbar [a custom bottom navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdjbW.png)

I've tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inset-shadow but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, you need to add your minimum code to show your effort and clarify what is the issue you 're facing, don't add link for the image, you can show it directly

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create curved views in React Native using a combination of `borderRadius`, `overflow`, and a `custom shape`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const CurvedView = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.curved}>
        {/* Your content goes here */}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  curved: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 100,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    transform: [{ scaleX: 2 }],
  },
});

export default CurvedView;
```